# Trigger JQuery function after quicktime reaches end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quicktime

I read the Apple documentation on how to make use of the DOM events for Quicktime. I am having trouble making it work within JQuery... I'd like to make use of the fade() function - that's why within JQuery.

Here's the code:

```
function onm_remove_intro(){

    $('#basecamp_intro_div').fadeOut(4000);

}; //end function onm_remove_intro()

function onm_add_event_listener(object, event, handlerfunction, capture_bool){

    if ( document.addEventListener )
        {object.addEventListener(event, handlerfunction, capture_bool)}
    else
        // IE
        {object.attachEvent('on' + event, handlerfunction)};

}; //end function onm_add_event_listener(object, event, handlerfunction, capture_bool)


var listener_object = $('#intro_movie_embed');

onm_add_event_listener(listener_object, 'qt_ended', onm_remove_intro, false);
```

Unless I comment out the last line, the execution of onm_add_event_listener, any JQuery code after it does not run. So clearly I am doing something illegal, but cannot figure out what.

I verified that the listener object variable does return a valid DOM object in Safari, which is where I am testing for now. Not concerned with IE yet.

Here is a reference to Apple's documentation on the subject:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW5

Hoping it's something really simple and that I am just too bleary eyed at this point to see it... All I want to do, if it isn't evident from the code example is to fade out the video after it reaches the end.

Thanks in advance,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having any experience with quicktime DOM events it seems to me the `listener_object` should be the DOM element, instead of the jquery object.

Have you tried:

```
var listener_object = $('#intro_movie_embed').get(0);
```

Comment: Ditto! Dit not know the difference. I guess I have been using JQuery so much I forgot there was one!